# Fetch an url img data and set it in a src attribute of an img in my html

Tags: javascript, html, image, fetch, src

I ´m fetching from a weather api information to my app. I manage to bring and change info in my html for the "location-timezone", "temperature-degree" and "tempemperature-description"; but I´m having trouble changing mi "temperature-icon" to de api icon.

This is the section of my html I am working:

```
<div>
  <div class="w-location">
    <h6 class="location-timezone">Timezone</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="w-icon">
    <img id="temp-icon" src="imagenes/calendar.png">
  </div>
  <div class="w-temperature">
    <p class="temp-degree">7 ° <span>C</span></p>
    <p class="col-6 temp-description"> Freezen </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my javasript where I bring the info from de api and made the functions to change info in my html:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 let long;
 let lat;
 let data;
 let newIcon;
 let locationTimezone = document.querySelector(".location-timezone");
 let tempDescription = document.querySelector(".temp-description");
 let tempDegree = document.querySelector(".temp-degree");

 if (navigator) {
   long = -87.627778;
   lat = 41.881944;

   const api = `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json? 
   key=db5d332edd014d29aa1175108201908&q=${lat},${long}`;

   fetch(api)
     .then(response => {
     return response.json();
     })
     .then(function (json) {
     data = json;
 
     //set DOM elements from the API
     locationTimezone.textContent = data.location.tz_id;
     tempDescription.textContent = data.current.condition.text;
     tempDegree.textContent = data.current.temp_c;
     newIcon = data.current.condition.icon;  
     })
   } else {
      h1.textContent = "Geolocation not working"
   }
});
```

How can I set the newIcon information into my img (id=#temp-icon src="") in my html?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with either Javascript object or by setting the existing img src.

In your case

```
document.getElementById("temp-icon").src = newIcon; //assuming newIcon is the URL
```

Or you could create a new Javascript Image object and pass the icon image source to it.

```
let iconImage = new Image();
iconImage.src = newIcon;
```

Then add/append the `iconImage` object as your div's child. (`w-icon`)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

Comment: Thanks! it works! but I am having problems passing this info to my html (Sorry I am new on this!). If I console.log(iconImage) on my console appears ina perfect way the info (<img src="https://cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png">). but when i´m trying to paste it in my html It appears [objectHTMLImageElement], this is how I done it:

Comment: document.getElementById("w_icon").innerHTML = iconImage;

Comment: You can get the image src from your `iconImage` and then use one of the codes above